# How to check variable type?

Tags: templating, variable, variable-type

How do I check what type my variable of (string, integer, boolean, array, dictionary,  etc)?

Comment: Your solution may be the best one so far. It looks as if Twig has rejected adding this feature as it doesn't fall inline with the goals of Twig. https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/595

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed this feature today, so I've put together a simple plugin, which does the job: [Craft-TwigTypeTest](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigTypeTest)

**Example:**

```twig
{% set test_var = craft.entries %}

{% if test_var is of_type('object') %}
  true
{% endif %}
```

or

```twig
{% set test_var = craft.entries %}

{{ test_var|get_type }}
{# Outputs: object #}
```

Comment: Very nice, Victor!

Answer (score 14):

To my knowledge this is not possible natively in Twig. Depending on your situation / template needs here are some useful tests

`{% if foo is iterable %}`

Array or object

`{% if foo is same as(true) %}`

Basically identical to using === in php

Answer (score 7):

I recently needed to check if a variable is a number. My first idea was to use the `divisibleby` test:

```twig
{# DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED! #}
{% if var is divisible by(1) %}
{% endif %}
```

Unfurtunatelly twig returns `true` for every string passed to it.

But what you can do is to use regular expressions using the [`matches`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons) operator in the comparison. You'll note that I double escaped the dot and the meta-character `\d`, this is because of a [twig bug](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/pull/1457) (or put otherwise: [wrong documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons) of using regex here).

```twig
{# Match integer #}
{% if var matches '/^\\d+$/' %}
{% endif %}

{# Match floating point number #}
{% if var matches '/^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$/' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: very nice , i didn t know u can regex in twig

Answer (score 4):

I hit a snag for this where I needed to check if a value was a boolean type. This isn't the greatest approach, but it does work and is easy to interpret:

```
{% if value is same as(false) or value is same as(true) %}
```

Documentation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html